# java get url of html file that is in project package

Tags: java

In my project, I have created a package that am calling htmlRepository. In this package, I have created an Html file called mapping.html. I would like to access this file, convert it to a url so I can use the *setPage* method to  diplay it in a JEditorPan.How can I access this file in order to get its url.
I have used the code below to do this if the file resides outside the project package i.e on some folder on my computer.

```
NodeName = Node;
           try {
          NodeURL = new File(filename).toURI().toURL();      
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

However, this means that when I create the jar then I will have to have another folder with the HTML.So I created the Html package so I can carry the Html files in the jar and access them from there. How can I go about this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to access it as a [resource](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load it as a resource file using the context class loader as so:

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
```

and by filename you should include the full nested directories before your file starting from the resources dir

Comment: Why would you do all of that? Why not just `getClass().getResource(filename)`?

Comment: Well technically it depends on the use of the OP. Usually I prefer this one, it's a sure go if you're working with more threads, and in terms of perfornance it changes nothing

Comment: The solution worked for me.When i am using eclipse i can see both the html text and images,however when i launch the  jar file i only see the html text and the images are left out.I had put my images in the same package as the html files and callling them by for example  <IMG SRC="file:GettingStarted.jpg"    width="2000" height="40" > in the html file.Do you know how i can go about this?

Comment: @alvy you might ask that question as a new question then. You want to know how to access resource files from your jar.